# warning: comparison between pointer and integer in C

Tags: c, pointers, warnings, getcwd

I get a warning

`warning: comparison between pointer and integer`

on the line containing `if` from the next piece of code:

```
char cwd[1024];

if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) != (char*)NULL)
    printf("%s\n",cwd);
else
    error_print("error in pwd");
```

how and what do I need to fix?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you include unistd.h? If not, the error appears because your C compiler is assuming getcwd returns int.

The fix? Include unistd.h

Comment: i am not getting any error but just warning only , is there any prototype def in stdio.h or stdlib.h 
-----------------------------
int getcwd(char *buf, size_t size);

Answer (score 4):

The prototype of [getcwd](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getcwd) is

```
char *getcwd(char *buf, size_t size);
```

Make sure you include `<unistd.h>` otherwise the return type would default to `int`.

Here, even Ideone gives its [Current Working Directory](http://www.ideone.com/hURHp)

Answer (score 0):

have you included the .h necessary so that the compiler understands what getcwd returns?

the behavior of your c compilers is probably to assume an int return value from every undefined function.

Answer (score -1):

In the return types section of the following link, getcwd returns null on failure.  Thus, instead of checking for `!= (char *)NULL` just check for `!= NULL`

http://linux.die.net/man/3/getcwd

Comment: Good practice, but it won't fix the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Modify line with this one `if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) != NULL)`

Comment: Good practice, but it won't fix the issue.